# Hint for KKT Optimization problem

Tags: analysis, optimization, random-variables, nonlinear-optimization

Can anyone help me with the following optimization problem please?

I have to find the 
$\max f(c,y_1^1,\cdots,y_{N-1}^1,\cdots,y_1^M,\cdots,y_{N-1}^M)=c$

subject to the constraints 
$\mathbb{E}[\exp{(-\alpha_i(X_i(w_j)+Y_i(w_j)))}]\leq \gamma$ and
$Y_i(w_j)>b_i$

where $\gamma,\alpha_i,c,b_i$ are constants, and $X_i,Y_i$ are random variables.
I know I have to use KKT, can anyone help me only with the lagrangian and the conditions please?

Any kind of help will be much appreciated!